# Resampling fmri images using R

Tags: r, image, matlab, resampling

I would like to resample a fmri image (nii or.img) with dimensions 53x63x46 to an new image with 256x256x256.

In fact, I just need the new 3D array (matrix).

In R would be:

```
NEWIMAGE [1:256,1:256,1:256]
```

If is not possible, do you know how SPM (matlab)does it? If possible, the code.

Source image files, example:

IMG Dimension (53x63x46) : https://www.dropbox.com/s/25oa0wr7prbcbl7/fica_3.img?dl=0

HDR: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4quyx60wraiw2o4/fica_3.hdr?dl=0

Result using SPM:

New IMG Dimension (256x256x256): https://www.dropbox.com/s/y4ut9ttrj964q8c/ica3.nii?dl=0

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you'd like to provide one or two images...

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/25oa0wr7prbcbl7/fica_3.img?dl=0 let me know if you need the .hdr file as well. Thanks

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4quyx60wraiw2o4/fica_3.hdr?dl=0 the hdr file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to do it using R specifically, but I will present two ways to do it:

1 - Using Fresurfer:

```
#!/bin/bash
export FREESURFER_HOME=~/Neuro/freesurfer # your folder...
source $FREESURFER_HOME/SetUpFreeSurfer.sh

mri_convert -rl reference_image.img -rt interpolate image_to_resample.img new_image.img
```

2 - Using FSL:

```
flirt -in image_to_resample.img -ref ref_image.img -out new_image.img -applyisoxfm 1
```

Also you can use SPM, "Coregister (Reslice)".

Hope it helps!